# Pokemon go email

Tags: pokemon-go

What happens if you forgot your email and you can't activate your account. Is there some way you can retrieve your email for that account? Any info will help.

Answer (score 0):

The mail was sent to the email you put in.
If you already have forgotten it i would say check all your mails.

If it isnt you made made an typo and you simply put you cant activate it.

If you do know the username by any chance you could try to contact support to help you out.

Else create a new one, you might be better off in the end since support is going to take awhile